# Calculate Decimal Xor for two decimal Numbers using PHP

Tags: php, numbers, logical-operators

I want to Xor these two decimal numbers using PHP. I've tried the bitwise operator XOR( ^ )  but the output is wrong since I want it in decimal also.

first Number =121065035052

second Number =210022101
expected decimal xored output= 121274989561

```
echo  210022101 ^ 121065035052 ;
```

the output of this echo statement is : 1015905273

Please  help me with that. Thanks in advance

Comment: "I've tried this function but..." - what function?

Comment: @Hallur ^ function

Comment: It works here: http://phptester.net/

Comment: oh, that's a bitwise operator.. thus my confusion

Comment: The only possible situation I can see that *not* working is if you're running 32bit PHP. What is the output of `var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX);`?

Comment: @Sammitch the output is int 2147483647

Comment: @LuizEduardodeChristo It's very strange since on my machine gives me the output result above.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX);` on your machine?

Comment: You're running 32bit PHP. You can't compute a number larger than that without using [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).

Comment: Can confirm, only works if you run 64bit PHP. Does not work with 32bit PHP.

Comment: Same here, tested my laptop (32 bit) and my stationary (64 bit). It worked on stationary. Solution is to reinstall php but 64 bit installation

Comment: It doesn't work after using this code $v1=121065035052;
$v2=210022101;
$a = gmp_init($v1);
$b = gmp_init($v2);
echo gmp_intval($a) ^ gmp_intval($b);

Comment: Oh beg pardon, it gives an error

Comment: It does not like the size of the first number

Answer (score 0):

The first number 121065035052 is a 37-bit number, so your code only works on 64-bit PHP.
For compatibility with 32-bit PHP, use GMP.

```
$a = gmp_init('121065035052');
$b = gmp_init('210022101');
$c = gmp_xor($a,$b);

echo gmp_strval($c);
```

The output is 121274989561 as expected.